# How to remove special characters from csv file while importing into sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, import

```
Since i cant ask new questions i'm editing my older questions, I have an csv file named barcode, i have successfully imported that into my sqlite db but the problem is while importing the values are inserted with special characters like what we have in csv file.
```

my barcode db:

```
EAN_CODE    ITEM
   8.90103E+12  100047253
   8.90103E+12  100047253
   8.90103E+12  100047253
```

i want to remove the special chars in my EAN_CODE column, i have tried this:

```
    String[] str = line.split(",");

                        arrayList_stock2.add(new 
    MasterDataModel2(str[0].replaceAll("\"", ""), 
    str[1].replaceAll("\"","")));
```

Comment: Use [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) else you will face problem while uploading on play store

Comment: Google has restricted use of sms read permission. You can find more details here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303
You should use SMS Retriever API as suggested by @ManoharReddy

Comment: Goggle has restricted SMS and PHONE read Permission while uploading on Play Store you will get error.So use SMS retriver api suggested by Manohar Reddy  Or If you are using Firebase Auth,there is no need for SMS retriever.You can study tutorials for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying in way which need SMS permission and it is restricted by **google**. 
For more information read [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303).

Instead this they have intruduced

[Automatic SMS Verification with the SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)

> You can do SMS-based user verification in your Android app
>   automatically, without requiring the user to manually type
>   verification codes, and without requiring any extra app permissions
>   with SMS Retriever API.

Comment: Welcome and best of luck.